# How to upload a image to a specifc cell in a table using JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

I am using JavaScript to upload images to a table on another page on the site. The current that I'm currently using looks like this.

```
<td width="10%">1</td>
                <td width="10%"><?php if(file_exists('upload_folder/1.jpg')){ ?><img src="upload_folder/1.jpg" /><?php }else{ echo "No Picture";} ?></td>
                <td width="60%">This is product number 1</td>
                <td width="10%"></td>
                <td width="10%"></td>
```

This code is great as long as I know in advanced, what the "product ID" is going to be, however the table is going to be updated at different times (and I don't know how many products there are going to be), so I won't know what the ID will be.

I would like it so that when an admin user uploads an image, they can put the image into a particular cell without knowing the product ID.

So far, I've tried using $productID = $_POST['productid']; and scandir(). however, these don't seem to work.

I hope someone, will be able to help, and that I haven't made this too confusing (I'm a little confused myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably several ways to approach this. One would be to have a file with all the product IDs in it. Open the file and build your table using this info. When you add each row to the display table, look for a corresponding image in your image folder. If found, add it. Otherwise put the 'no image' text in.

Comment: While that would work, the problem is that I won't know all of the product ids seeing as new items will added al the time.

Comment: Use AJAX or a form to maintain a list of products. When one is added you update the file / db / whatever.

Comment: For the time being, I'm going with the current system that I have and just have 10 rows with each product ID being numbered 1-10 and so the image can be changed to represent a new product. Ideally I'd like to be have so that I can add another row (or more) to the table and add the image to the image cell without knowing the ID but this'll have to do for now.